# How can I share sessions between a Rails3 app and Cramp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin, rack-pow

I have a Rails3 app running on pow (in development) and a Cramp application running on thin. I'm using cookie based sessions in Rails and I want the Cramp to be able to access the session created by Rails.

Any idea how this can be done? I'm fairly new to Ruby and Rails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out how to get this working with SSE's but I'm currently debugging an interesting issue that maybe you could help me with.

So I created the following ApplicationAction

```
class ApplicationAction < Cramp::Action
    before_start :load_session

    def load_session
        session_id = request.cookies['_session_id']
        @session = Session.where(:session_id => session_id).first
        yield
    end
end
```

This made the rails session available to all my child actions. I then added a session model (I used cramp with ActiveRecord) and the following model.

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name :sessions

    # Get the data on the sessions table
    def data; Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(read_attribute(:data))); end
end
```

This actually works perfectly assuming that all the classes that are Marshal serialized can be instantiated. Which is where I am at a problem. This causes problems with ActionDispatch when it is serialized by rails into the session data.

I am currently in the process of trying to find a better solution.